# Does AWS Console uses Amplify library for Cognito Auth?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

To clear up the question.

At AWS `Sign In` page i can see that AWS uses `Cognito`.

But what I could not dig out with my Javascript debugging skills, is Amplify used as a library for Oauth in `AWS Console` frontend?

I guess minification and "obfuscation" blocks me to debug in any other way.

EDIT:

These are the headers sent from browser so I guess they are not using Amplify but aws-sdk-js.

Here are the headers and thanks for the comments.

```
headers: {X-Amz-User-Agent: "aws-sdk-js/2.324.0 promise", Content- 
Type: "application/x-amz-json-1.1",…}
Content-Type: "application/x-amz-json-1.1"
X-Amz-Target: 
"AmazonEC2ContainerRegistry_V20150921.DescribeRepositories"
X-Amz-User-Agent: "aws-sdk-js/2.324.0 promise"
method: "POST"
operation: "describeRepositories"
params: {}
path: "/"
region: "us-east-1"
```

Comment: AWS is not communicating about the technologies they use to build their services.  Why do you need to know (beside curiosity :-) ?  How knowing this will help you to build better apps on AWS ?

Comment: Simple curiosity. Nothing more.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a platform meant for discussing possible internal architectures of cloud services. This sort of a question would be a better fit for r/aws on Reddit instead, or maybe even a Facebook group. I suggest you to go through community standards before posting questions.

Comment: It is not internal architecture. It is frontend javascript which uses one of their services, Cognito. There is nothing internal about it.

Comment: "It is frontend javascript which uses one of their services, Cognito." 
Do you have any Screenshots or logged Network API calls to back that up?

Comment: Basically wanted to ask if they use their own library. And yes they are but not Amplify, instead aws-sdk-js.